# Having problems using ApiService in android project using retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit

I have developed a web page using laravel and now I want to communicate with an android app I´m making. I´m using retrofit but I have some problems with the APiService.
Here´s my ApiService:

```
package com.example.retrofitpruebabuena.API;
import com.example.retrofitpruebabuena.models.Alumno;

import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Path;
import retrofit2.http.Query;

public interface ApiService {
    @GET("api/courses/")
    Call<List<Alumno>> getStudents(@Query("course") int course);
}
```

Here´s my API:

```
package com.example.retrofitpruebabuena.API;

import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class API {

    public static final String BASE_URL="http://tfg.test/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getApi(){
        if (retrofit==null){
            retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }


}
```

Here´s my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ApiService service= API.getApi().create(ApiService.class);
        Call<List<Alumno>> alumnosCall=service.getStudents(25);

        alumnosCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<Alumno>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Alumno>> call, Response<List<Alumno>> response) {
                List<Alumno> alumnos=response.body();

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Alumno>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Errorrr", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });


    }
}
```

When I use the web page this is the url that appears in the borwser: http://tfg.test/api/courses/26. The "26" is a parameter indicating the course. I don´t know how to make the call in the ApiService. Because I have read that @Query would be in case the url was: http://tfg.test/api/courses/?course=26 but in my case I have no idea how it would be.
Thank you.

Comment: Try reading [this](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/Path.html)

Comment: @OhhhThatVarun I have tried that:@GET("api/courses/{course}")
    Call<List<Alumno>> getStudents(@Path("course") int course); but it doesn`t work